# Why does defining new match in Vim remove the previously defined one?

Tags: vim, match, syntax-highlighting, highlight

To show trailing whitespace in Vim, I use the following:

```
highlight whitespaceEOL term=reverse ctermbg=Grey guibg=Grey
match whitespaceEOL /\s\+\(\%#\)\@!$/
```

When I use the following match for long lines, the first match is lost:

```
augroup longLines
    autocmd! filetype zsh,sh,python,vim,c,cpp :match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
augroup END
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`:match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:match) only matches one pattern at a time.  [`:2match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:2match) and [`:3match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:3match) exist for exactly this reason.  Try this:

```
2match whitespaceEOL /\s\+$/
3match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
```

Alternatively, you can implement this as [`syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syntax).  Try this:

```
syntax match whitespaceEOL /\s\+$/
syntax match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
```

Comment: is a solution use `syn match ...` ?

Comment: but, I can make definitions `syn match ...` in ~/.vimrc for many filetypes ?

Comment: I added this  

    highlight whitespaceEOL term=reverse ctermbg=Grey guibg=Grey
    syn match whitespaceEOL /\s\+\(\%#\)\@!$/

but don't work

Comment: I use you second solution (syntax match ...), but don't work for me

Comment: only work, if I make `syntax clear | syn match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/` but lost other syntax